# IE Mode for MS Edge

Tags: selenium-webdriver, microsoft-edge, remote-debugging, ie-compatibility-mode

I am struggling to open my edge browser in IE compatibility mode, my organisation has made a universal setting to open my application in IE mode of Edge. When I try to open that application manually it works fine but when I open it using selenium webdriver, it gives me an error to disable remote debugging so that application can work in desired form.

I am not able to locate any key/capability to disable remote debugging or to open my edge browser in ie compatibility mode. Please help.

Selenium version: 3.141.59
Edge version:85

Comment: Which language are you using to automate Edge? You could refer to the section **Automating Internet Explorer mode** in [this article](https://blogs.windows.com/msedgedev/2019/11/04/edge-chromium-release-candidate-get-ready/) about how to use IE mode in Edge Chromium in Selenium C#. Note that using the latest version of IEDriverServer such as 3.150.1 and making sure to close all the Edge browser tabs and window before running the code.

Comment: m using java for automating edge. I did not find any capability to set ie mode for edge chromium.

Comment: Yes, it can't work with Java. We're also researching about this. We'll inform you if we get any solution or workaround.

Comment: @YuZhou did you find a way to launch edge browser in IE with Java?