# How to launch Edge browser in IE mode using java selenium?

Tags: java, selenium

We have the options to open edge in ie mode using c#. Not it selenium java

Code -

```
WebDriver driver; 

System.setProperty("webdriver.ie.driver", "D:\\SG\\Downloads\\IEDriverServer_Win32_3.150.2\\IEDriverServer.exe"); 
InternetExplorerDriverService ieService= InternetExplorerDriverService.createDefaultService(); 

InternetExplorerOptions ieOptions= new InternetExplorerOptions();

ieOptions.setCapability("ie.edgechromium", true); 

ieOptions.setCapability("ie.edgepath", "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft\\Edge\\Application\\msedge.exe"); 

driver= new InternetExplorerDriver(ieOptions);
```

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 1):

Currently the option of launching Edge browser in IE Mode is only available via the C# bindings for Selenium. You will not be able to achieve this using Java bindings.

Reference - Please see the answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65902742/how-to-open-microsoft-edge-in-internet-explorerie-mode-using-python-and-seleni) and also comment from one of the committers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64421625/ie-mode-for-ms-edge) ( see the comments in the question)